# SAS &SYSERRORTEXT variable removing quote to use in SQL

Tags: sas

I'm trying to use SAS system variables to track batch program execution (SYSERRORTEXT, SYSERR, SYSCC, ...)

I want to insert those in a dataset, using PROC SQL, like this :

Table def :

```
PROC SQL noprint;
CREATE TABLE WORK.ERROR_&todaydt. (
    TRT_NM VARCHAR(50)
    ,DEB_EXE INTEGER FORMAT=DATETIME.
    ,FIN_EXE INTEGER FORMAT=DATETIME.
    ,COD_ERR VARCHAR(10)
    ,LIB_ERR VARCHAR(255)
    ,MSG_ERR VARCHAR(1000)
)
;
RUN;
QUIT;
```

Begin execution :

```
PROC SQL noprint;
    INSERT INTO WORK.ERROR_&todaydt. VALUES("&PGM_NAME", %sysfunc(datetime), ., '', '', '';
RUN;
QUIT;
```

End execution :

```
PROC SQL noprint;
    UPDATE WORK.ERROR_&todaydt. 
        SET 
        FIN_EXE = %sysfunc(datetime())
        ,COD_ERR = "&syserr"
        ,LIB_ERR = ''
        ,MSG_ERR = "&syserrortext"
    WHERE TRT_NM = "&PGM_NAME"
    ;
RUN;
QUIT;
```

The problem occurs with system variable &syserrortext. which may contains special char, espcially single quote ('), like this

Code example for problem :

```
DATA NULL;
    set doesnotexist;
RUN;
```

and so, &syserrortext  give us : ERROR: Le fichier WORK.DOESNOTEXIST.DATA n'existe pas.

my update command is failing with this test, so how i can remove special chars from my variable &syserrortext ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, which avoids the need to remove special characters, is to simply use `symget()`, eg as follows:

```
,MSG_ERR = symget('syserrortext')
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to quote the value. First use macro quoting in case the value contains characters that might cause trouble. Then add quotes so that the value becomes a string literal. Use the `quote()` function to add the quotes in case the value contains quote characters already.  Use the optional second parameter so that it uses single quotes in case the value contains `&` or `%` characters.

```
,MSG_ERR = %sysfunc(quote(%superq(syserrortext),%str(%')))
```